# How to view Vec<u64> as Vec<u8> without copying in Rust?

Tags: rust

As the title says. Is there a noncopy way to view `Vec<u64>` or `[u64;4]` as `Vec<u8>` or `[u8;256]` ?

After all I guess it could be made via unsafe block, ptr ... but how?

And maybe there is another 'safe' way?

Comment: also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56973284/how-do-i-convert-a-vecu8-to-vecu64

Comment: As that post says, you _almost certainly_ want a `&[u8]` and not a `Vec<u8>`.